# Kinfu LargeScale App PCL does not free GPU memory

Tags: c++, cuda, point-cloud-library

I'm using the KinfuLSApp repeatedly in a while loop to convert series of pcd's (which present 1 frame each) into a world pcd. This made me find out that when the KinfuLSApp destructor gets called, the memory used in the gpu does not get freed. This resulted in an "out of memory" exception after a few iterations.

How would I solve this problem? The KinfuLSApp does not have a pointer to the used device. I figured calling cudaFree could possibly release the memory but I need a device pointer for that. This is where I'm stuck.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with what you are doing, but `cudaDeviceReset()` should erase *all* allocations on the (currently selected) device.

Comment: I fixed the problem, but I figured I'd respond to this: a full devicereset could be risky depending on what other tasks you're performing at the time, I think. I posted the reason for the memory leak below.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer to a PCDGrabber wasn't released and started hogging the internal memory of my GPU. Problem solved!